# How do I only show the Top 10 popular places by %?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
plt.figure (figsize=(12,10))

df['Places'].value_counts().plot.pie(autopct="%1.1f%%")

plt.ylabel('Popular places', size = 20)

plt.title('Most Popular places in my city by %', size = 20)

plt.show()
```

This is what I have. It does gives me a pie chart with 50+ places and does not look appealing. I want to only show 10 top places by percentage. How can I do that? Please help!!